# More accurate function execution time out of a shared "noise" computer?

Tags: c, linux, benchmarking

I am doing benchmark on a "supercomputer" (not a literal one but a computer stuff with tons of ram and cpu).

The problem is the computer is shared by many people.

Is any measure to obtain a more accurate measurement of functional execution time (written in C)

Or can I measure the "background" noise and discount it from the measurement?

My current scheme is to use the function in 
http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/03/c_c_tip_how_measure_cpu_time_benchmarking

It uses POSIX timer to get cpu time, but I find this still still affected by the "background noise" of the computer

scenario:
I reimplement the sorting routine in SQLite with linear time sorting function. I tried to benchmark it in the in-memory database of SQLite. Every Time I insert 5 million rows of random record, I execute an "order by" query (sorted by random 64-bit integer), and only time the query time. And below is the result. You can observe, there a lot of sudden sharp drop on the graph.

[image: benchmark]

Comment: Why do you think it is inaccurate? How did you test exactly?

Comment: I am benchmarking a linear time sorting function and its running sometime decrease sharply when I increase the size of dataset.

Comment: Did you consider IO variations and cache/RAM contention?

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve] with all relevant information. It might still be off-topic, though.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit the question with full detail

Comment: to acquire the CPU time for your application, use `clock_gettime( CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &myTimeSpec );`   Note variations will still be seen, depending on CPU cache hits/misses, the content of the actual data, the amount of actual data, the order of the actual data, etc.

Comment: @user3629249: That's what I was going to say: measure CPU time taken rather than wall-clock time.  But the OP is already doing this (POSIX cpu time).  You can also use performance counters to actually record numbers of cache misses, or other events like that.  However, if waiting for disk I/O is part of the total time, it's going to be hard to get consistent results.  The less CPU time your process gets, the more time there is for disk I/O to complete while your process is delayed.  And contention for disk I/O is a huge confounding factor, and harder to measure.  Esp. on a non-SSD.

Comment: Getting multiple samples for each data point (dataset size) and averaging is probably a good way to go.  It's maybe worth measuring cache misses with `perf stat` or something.  If your process was interrupted by context switches to another process often, then it will have a lot more cache misses.  So maybe keep the best 2 of 4 runs for each data point?